# Computing the profit given the probability of winning in a sport bet

Tags: probability, gambling

Suppose that you can correctly predict the outcome of a tennis match (i.e. the winner) with probability $x > 0.5$. If you gamble on $N$ matches on some betting website, where odds are assigned by the bookmakers to each outcome, what is the minimum $x$ to make profit? Given $x$, how to compute the profit after $N$ matches?

Comment: Assuming that you bet $1$ unit, on a single match, with probability of $x > (1/2)$ of winning, and assuming that you will either win $(+1)$ or lose $(+1)$, then the expected result from this particular bet is $$(x \times 1) + ([1-x] \times [-1]) = 2x - 1.$$

Comment: Did you mean you make N bets on different betting websites? Your expected return ( you loss or make profit) depends on the odds that bookmakers give you. Example: if you correctly predict the result 53% to happen but the bookmaker only give you 0.8 odd, then you will lose money in the long run if you bet similar matches like this.